# NHibernate - Associations in memory not updated

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the following problem model:

```
class Item
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set;}

    // Bi-directional mapping to simplify object traversal.
    public virtual Storage Storage { get; set; }
}

class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    // Bi-directional mapping to simplify object traversal.
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

class Storage
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set;}
}
```

The problem is that whenever I delete a `Storage` object containing some `Item` instances as follows :

```
Category category = ...; // This instance already exists in the database. 
Storage storage = ...; // This instance already exists in the database.

Item item = new Item();
item.Category = category; // Inverse is used on HasMany association
category.Items.add(item);
item.Storage = storage; // Inverse is used on HasMany association
storage.Items.add(item);
session.Save(storage);
session.Flush();

// HasMany association on Storage cascades delete to Item
session.Delete(Storage);
session.Flush();
```

the `Item` still remains in `Category.Items`. Is this behavior expected? Or is it necessary to explicitly remove the deleted `Item` instances from the parent `Category`?

Answer (score 0):

I am no more able to find a reference for following statement, but I believe NHibernate considers that removing a deleted entity from loaded `one-to-many` collections is not its responsibility.

If you have some remaining work to do on your already loaded category, you should then remove explicitly the deleted items, or [`Refresh` (see end of 9.2§)](http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/manipulatingdata.html#manipulatingdata-loading) the category.

If you have some remaining work to do with the currently opened session, without having anymore knowledge of which `Category` are hold in its first level cache with their `Items` loaded and containing some deleted ones, and requiring any `Category` yielded by this session to have its `Items` up to date, you may then `Clear` the session before going on. (This will evict all loaded entities.)

But it would be better to simply finish the unit of work at your Flush. (Close the session.) `Category` loaded from (or attached into) a newly opened session would have their `Items` up to date.